# Solving following irrational inequaltiy

Tags: inequality

Here is the inequality: $$x-3<(x^2+4x-5)^{1/2}.$$

My try: First of all I know for RHS to be defined $x^2+4x-5$ should be greater than $0$,so I got the intervals $[-\infty,-5]\cup[1,\infty]$, then I squared both sides and got $x>(7/5)$. So the overall answer is $((7/5),\infty)$ but this is not correct. So my question is where am I wrong and how should I correct?

Comment: You could square both sides to get $x^2-6x+9<x^2+4x-5$, which can be re-arranged to $14<10x$, hence $x>1.4=7/5$. Why do you believe this is not correct?

Comment: because  the answer is given as [-infinity,-5]U(union)[1,infinity] in the book.and according to the graph also this answer is true but how to do it algebrically.

Comment: ...small point use round brackets for $\pm \infty$ as neither of $\pm \infty$ are in the set of real numbers... $[a,\infty)$ is just notation for $x\geq a$.

Comment: Why would you want to do it algebraically? Is graphing a serious issue?

Comment: @Gummybears i meant just using pen and paper and not using tools like graphing software

Comment: I see. But it won't be too difficult to sketch this by hand either.

Comment: I can draw rough sketch of both LHS and RHS but how to get particular solution using  that rough graph.

Comment: Have you drawn the graph before squaring or after?

Comment: before squaring

Comment: Do you see that the graphs don't intersect at any point?

Comment: No rough sketch doesnt give enough information

Answer (score 2):

I would probably think like this. If $x-3<0$ and $x^2+4x+5\geq 0$ then the inequality certainly holds. This is $x<3$ and (if you analyse the geometry of the quadratic) $x\leq -5$ or $x\geq 1$.

This means that the inequality certainly holds for $x\leq -5$ and $1\leq x<3$.

If you can't follow this you should draw a schematic graph and/or numberline.

Now what if $x-3\geq 0\Rightarrow x\geq 3$?  Now assume that $x$ satisfies the above inequality $I_1$ and $x\geq 3$. Well in this case both sides are positive and squaring is order preserving so if you square both sides you get a new inequality $I_2$ (such that all solutions of $I_1$ satisfy $I_2$). This new inequality has the solution $x\geq 7/5$. So we have

$$\underbrace{[x\geq 3]}_{=:A}\text{ and }\underbrace{[x\text{ satisfies }I_1]}_{=:B}\Rightarrow [x\text{ satisfies }I_2]\Rightarrow [x\geq \frac75]\Rightarrow \underbrace{[x\geq 3]}_{=A} \text{ or }\underbrace{[\frac75\leq x<3]}_{=:C}.$$

So you have a situation where $A$ and $B$ implies something stronger than $A$, namely $A$ or $C$ ($A\cap B\Rightarrow A\cup C$). Therefore $A\Rightarrow B$ ... [somebody might be able to explain this logic a little better than I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363356/a-cap-b-rightarrow-a-cup-c-implies-a-rightarrow-b)... it can be understood using truth tables or Venn diagrams.

**EDIT:** *Henning has explained that this particular logic is flawed.*

Therefore the answer is $\mathbb{R}\backslash (-5,1)=(-\infty,-5]\cup[1,\infty)$.

So when your root is defined --- outside $(-5,1)$ --- your root is positive and you have three situations:

- for $x\leq -5$, $x-3$ is negative and so less than any root
- for $1\leq x <3 $, $x-3$ is negative and so less than any root
- for $x\geq 3$, $x-3$ is positive but less than this particular square root

Outside these regions the root is undefined so there are no solutions.

Comment: How did you came to this conclusion "for x≥3, x−3 is positive but less than this particular square root"

Comment: @KartikWatwani I have given more details but I am not sure will you be convinced by the logic... someone else might row in here.

Comment: The logic here doesn't work -- you cannot reason from $(A\land B)\to(A\lor C)$ to $A\to B$.

Answer (score 0):

When you square both sides of the inequality, you can only be sure to preserve the ordering if both sides were non-negative in the first place.

The square root is always nonnegative if it exists, of course, but $x-3$ is only nonnegative for $x\ge 3$. So you need to divide into two cases:

1. When $x<3$, then $x-3$ is negative, and therefore automatically smaller than the square root whenever the square root exists.
2. When $x\ge 3$, then your square-and-rearrange is valid, so in that case you need the square root to exist and $x>\frac75$. But both of these conditions are true for every $x\ge 3$.

So no matter whether $x\ge 3$ or not, the inequality will be satisfied *whenever* the square root exists.

Comment: Is there a way to formalise the logic of part 2 somewhat... as I so pathetically failed to do!

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: What kind of formalisation do you find lacking? The assumption in this case is that $x\ge 3$. Under that assumption we find that the inequality holds if the square root exists and $x>\frac75$, both of which are easily seen to be the case when $x\ge 3$. Therefore $x\ge 3$ is a sufficient condition for the inequality to be true.