# $(A\text{ and } B)\Rightarrow (A\text{ or } C)$ implies $A\Rightarrow B$

Tags: logic

I used the logic in the title in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363311/solving-following-irrational-inequaltiy/1363321#1363321). Is this implication true and is there a simple explanation of why it is true?

Comment: The question is ill-formed. $\cap$ and $\cup$ are operators that take _sets_ and produce _set_, but $\Rightarrow$ is a _logical connective_ that needs to be placed between _propositions_. No matter what kind of things $A$, $B$ and $C$ are, there's no way to get the left-hand side to make sense.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Looking at the original question, it seems it should be usual conjunction/disjunction rather than intersection/union.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you... is this any better?

Comment: ...hmmm. How do I clear up the logic in the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363311/solving-following-irrational-inequaltiy/1363321#1363321

Comment: Note that $\land$ and $\lor$ can be typeset with `\land` and `\lor` (or alternatively with `\wedge` and `\vee`).

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ and $B$ are propositions, and the claim is that $(A\land B\rightarrow A\lor C)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not a valid implication.

$(A\land B)\Rightarrow (A\lor C)$ is a *tautology*, and $A\Rightarrow B$ is not. So the former cannot imply the latter.

For example, if $A$ is true but $B$ and $C$ are false, then $(A\land B)\Rightarrow (A\lor C)$ is true, but $A\Rightarrow B$ is false.